# "App not installed" error while trying to install Nexus Media Importer

Tags: applications, installation, nexus-5

I'm trying to install the Nexus Media Importer app with an APK file, but I am frequently getting an "App not installed" error. I am not rooted and I have Nexus 5.

Any solution?

Comment: Did you check `Security > Unknown sources`?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is the app you're trying to install already installed on the device (e.g. in an older version)? If you're installing it manually from an `.apk` file ([side-loading](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/side-loading/info)), do you have [unknown sources](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/unknown-sources/info) enabled?

Comment: Yeah  I have installed other apks like a million times, and the app I'm trying to install is not installed currently ..when i press install i get a message app not installed that's it..

Comment: [USB Media Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer) claimed to be Nexus Media Importer app back in the past, and it's a paid app. This may or may not affect the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Because this app checks your license. If you buy this app from the Play Store, it runs automatically. Otherwise, if you try a free version of this application, it shows the "application not installed" error.

Comment: While it's true that paid apps may check the license used in Play Store, I don't think the check is done on the installation.